# Schengen passport 10-year validity rules

Tags: schengen, passports, uk-citizens

The Schengen passport rules state that:

> If you are a non-EU national wishing to visit or travel within the EU, you will need a passport:
> valid for at least 3 months after the date you intend to leave the EU country you are visiting,
> which was issued within the previous 10 years

What I can't find is - does the validity in the first point refer to the expiry date on the passport, or the 10th anniversary of it's issue?

I am a UK citizen, with a passport issued before 2016, when leftover months were added to the new pasport - so mine has an expiry date 10y8m after the issue date. Can I therefore travel to the Schengen zone at, say, 9y10m (at which my passport is less than 10 years old, but still has 10 months remaining), or do I need to renew it prior to 9y9m (so my passport has 3 months less than 10 years since issue when I leave)?

Comment: Note that despite the actual rule, some border guards or airline agents (like the other question's OP) may insist otherwise and it may cause unwanted attention or hassle when you are travelling; so it might be advisable to renew the passport as soon as possible anyway.

Comment: thanks @xngtng, I missed that one in my search!